# rxjs with angular 2 - how to chain observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm making an app with angular2 and @ngrx/store... I'm new to rxjs and thinking in a reactive way... really struggling with how observables are chained.

I have an auth effect... currently looks like

```
@Effect() authenticate$ = this.updates$
.whenAction(AuthActions.AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST)
.switchMap(update => this.api.post('/authenticate', update.action.payload)
  .map((res:any) => this.authActions.authenticateSuccess(res.json()))
  .catch((err:any) => Observable.of(this.authActions.authenticateError(err)))
);
```

What I want to do is chain two extra actions when the request is successful.

1. Navigate to the "home" page after success with `this.router.navigate(['/'])`.
2. Store the credentials in a LocalStorage service `this.authService.store(credentials)`

What do I need to do to incorporate these actions in to the stream?

Comment: You're dispatching an authenticateSuccess action, so you should be handling this in another effect. That's particularly helpful when you have multiple ways of authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the order of execution of the last 2 statements is irrelevant, all you need to do is at the end of your current statement append

```
.flatMap(() =>
{
   this.router.navigate(['/']);
   this.authService.store(credentials);
});
```

Comment: Thanks... ok, will give that a go. is that after the .switchMap? or after the catch?

Comment: Yes, after the .switchMap

Comment: getting TypeScript errors from doing that... `Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Action, index: number) => Subscribable<{}> | Promise<{}> | ArrayLike<{}>'.`

Comment: My bad. flatMap needs to be chained to an Observable but you seem to have a promise. I would encapsulate the this.api.post call in an Observable or better still make it return an Observable. Then chain the flatMap to that Observable.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to keep your `effect` like this and add another one to react to success action like this:

```js
@Effect({dispatch: false}) authenticateSuccess$ = this.updates$
.whenAction(AuthActions.AUTHENTICATE_SUCCESS)
.do(credentials => {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    this.authService.store(credentials);
});
```

Where `{dispatch: false}` means "reacts to this action but don't send another".